# Will expressions break if it is unnecessary to continue?

Tags: c#

Lets say I have

```
if (textbox.Text != null && textbox.Text.Length > someNum)
{
    //some code
}
```

If textbox.Text is null, will it crash because null.Length doesn't work or will it break after the first expression because the operator is && and there's no point continuing?

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me clarify!

Comment: Wouldn't simply running the code have given you the answer?
If you were searching for 'why?', from your question you seem to be aware of that as well...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called "short-circuit evaluation," and C# has it.  So yes, if `textbox.Text` is null, it will not evaluate the second part of the expression.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=VS.71).aspx for specifics.

Comment: +1 was typing up almost an identical answer and link, just beat me to it.

Comment: Just to add to this:  the conditional & operator doesn't use short-circuiting (so both operands will be evaluated regardless of the result of the first).  This can be useful because the second evaluation may affect the state of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, C# does logic short-circuiting. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It will break after the first expression is found to be false.  This is called Short Circuiting and it is common to many modern languages (such as C# and Java.)

This is why it is often a good idea to check for null before checking another condition that depends upon an object not being null in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. However I would still break that line into checking Null : returning or throwing an exception. It makes the code clearer.